# Is there a more elegant way to overwrite A with B only if B is bigger than A?

Tags: java, integer, comparison

have some code in which I often do something like the following:

```
if(B > A) A = B;
```

And I was just wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this (using a minimal amount of variable references) as I am working with big nasty nested arrays and thus in my code it often looks more like:

```
if(A[1][5][9][201][600][0xff] > A[600][3][8][0xW/E][1337][6]) A[600][3][8][0xW/E][1337][6] = A[1][5][9][201][600][0xff];
```

And at some point I'm just going to lose track...

Please note that "0xW/E" is not a valid integer.

Comment: can you please describe, what is an elegant you from your perspective?

Comment: @StinePike mainly something in java which is meant for just this kind of thing, like ternary is sometimes very elegant <3

Comment: I think the issue here is your data scheme. Your big nasty nested arrays look highly unmaintainable, and I suggest you try refactoring it first; with that many axes of variability involved, I'd suggest using a database or a HashMap that takes a specified-length set of values (the original indices, perhaps) as its key.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I was not aware of this, thanks!

Comment: @JAB haha thanks, taken in to consideration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using `Math.max`?

```
A = Math.max(A,B);
```

Comment: My god this is exactly what i was looking for! Will I lose performance though?

Comment: Integer operations are among the quickest operations you can perform ;)

Comment: Great! Just imagine the possibilities! (A > B && A > C) VS (A > Math.max(B, C))

Comment: You may also want to look at [`Collections.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29) if you have a bunch of values that you want to find the maximum of.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of one of them:

```
newValue = A[600][3][8][0xW/E][1337][6];
if(A[1][5][9][201][600][0xff] > newValue) A[1][5][9][201][600][0xff] = newValue;
```

Comment: You can get rid of both since newValue would be a reference. This means i can combine this with Johan's answer and make it super ultra sexy :3

Answer (score 1):

What about this:    A = (A > B) ? A : B;

Comment: ternary! :3
Unfortunately that only looks bigger and nastier in this case D:

Comment: Funny, you found a way to make it even worse -- this has more variable references than the original, and that's what he's trying to minimize.

Comment: @Ryan not if this code is placed inside a method. Sadly (for Jairo) this is *done* in `Math#max`.